# formula to divide above row value

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am looking to create a formula that divides the cell above it by twelve. I would like to have this formula work for an entire row, and when the row number increases I would like the column letter to increase as well. Is this possible?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with examle of desired output

Answer (score 1):

see:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)/12
```

[image: 0]

arrayformula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1&":C"&ROW()-1)/12)
```

[image: 0]